# Call action with params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rxjs

I'm using React + Redux + Rxjs + `typesafe-actions` + TS and I want to call action with params. My code for now:

Actions:

```
import { createAsyncAction } from 'typesafe-actions';
import {ICats} from '/api/cats';

export const FETCH_CATS_REQUEST = 'cats/FETCH_CATS_REQUEST';
export const FETCH_CATS_SUCCESS = 'cats/FETCH_CATS_SUCCESS';
export const FETCH_CATS_ERROR = 'cats/FETCH_CATS_ERROR';

export const fetchCats = createAsyncAction(
    FETCH_CATS_REQUEST,
    FETCH_CATS_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_CATS_ERROR
) <void, ICats, Error> ();
```

Call dispatch:

```
store.dispatch(fetchCats.request());
```

My epics:

```
const fetchCatsFlow: Epic<Types.RootAction, Types.RootAction, Types.RootState> = (action$) =>
    action$.pipe(
        filter(isActionOf(fetchCats.request)),
        switchMap(() =>
            fromPromise(Cats.getDataFromAPI()).pipe(
                map(fetchCats.success),
                catchError(pipe(fetchCats.failure, of))
            )
        )
    );
```

API:

```
export const Cats = {
    getDataFromAPI: () => $http.get('/cats').then(res => {
        return res.data as any;
    }),
};
```

And it's working - making a call to API but without params. I tried many times and still I don't know how to pass a params when dispatch is called.

Comment: Where you want to pass the params? To `getDataFromAPI`?

Comment: I found a solution already, look below

Answer (score 2):

I found answer:

```
export const fetchCats = createAsyncAction(
    FETCH_CATS_REQUEST,
    FETCH_CATS_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_CATS_ERROR
) <void, ICats, Error> ();
```

changed to:

```
type ICatsRequest = {
    catType: string;
};

export const fetchCats = createAsyncAction(
    FETCH_CATS_REQUEST,
    FETCH_CATS_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_CATS_ERROR
) <ICatsRequest, ICats, Error> ();
```

and then it allows me to pass specified type to dispatch:

`store.dispatch(fetchCats.request({catType: 'XXX'}));`

also I needed to modify this:

```
export const Cats = {
    getDataFromAPI: (params) => $http.get('/cats', {
        params: {
            type: params.payload.catType
        }
    }).then(res => {
        return res.data as any;
    }),
};
```

and

```
switchMap((params) =>
        fromPromise(Cats.getDataFromAPI(params)).pipe(
            map(fetchCats.success),
            catchError(pipe(fetchCats.failure, of))
    )
)
```